# SVG math/other symbols in htlatex: Using something other than pstoedit

Tags: tex4ht, htlatex, svg, output

I have one file, and I want to alternately produce printable PDF files via `xelatex` and HTML pages via `htlatex`. By default, `htlatex` produces just really ugly, low-resolution PNG equations. I want SVG instead.

I do *not* want to use MathJaX. I want my file to work without JavaScript, and I don't want users to have to render the complex TeX every time.

Following advice online, I put this in `c.cfg`...

```
\Preamble{ext=htm,charset="utf-8",p-width,pic-align}
  \Configure{Picture}{.svg}  
  \makeatletter
  \Configure{graphics*}
  {svg}
  {
    {\Configure{Needs}{File: \Gin@base.svg}\Needs{}}
    \Picture[\csname a:GraphicsAlt\endcsname]{\csname Gin@base\endcsname.svg
            \csname a:Gin-dim\endcsname}
  }
  \begin{document}
\EndPreamble
```

Ran `htlatex` via `htlatex myfile "c"`...and, got this: `pstoedit: Unsupported output format svg`.

Hmm, what happened here? [Is my system misconfigured, as this Debian bug reporter thought](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=554518)? No. Perhaps at one point `pstoedit`'s SVG conversion was free software, but [not anymore](http://www.pstoedit.net/).

SVG is a shareware "plugin" of `pstoedit`, and there is no binary for my OS, FreeBSD.

**How can I have SVG math, and really SVG anything else marked between some command, with `htlatex` without `pstoedit`?**

I've determined that `htlatex` works internally by first generating an EPS file, e.g. `zztest.eps`. It then tries `pstoedit -f svg zztest.eps test0x.svg`. So I thought I'd just try another converter, but other converters, such as `uniconvertor` and `inkscape -z`, do not properly recognize LaTeX's magic, and put the EPS onto a huge canvas (see below). Also, it is cumbersome to have to run the other convertor every time, there should be a way to specify which convertor to use.

[image]

The image should look like the output of default `htlatex`, just as an SVG.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We should really replace `pstoedit` with something better. In reality, the process where we convert `DVI` to `PostScript` and then to `SVG` isn't really necessary today, as direct `DVI` do `SVG` convertor exists nowadays.

You can change the commands for image conversion in `tex4ht.env` file, but this process isn't really easy. Instead, I would use `make4ht`, which is modern replacement for `htlatex` with support for build files. You can specify custom commands for image conversion in these build files.

Save the following code as `test.mk4`:

```
Make:image("svg$","dvisvgm -n -p ${page} -c 1.4,1.4 -s ${source} > ${output}")
```

The build file is a Lua script, `Make:image` command provides command for image conversion. This command has two arguments, the first is configured image format (it is an regular expression, thus `$` at the end), the second is template for conversion command. There are three important parameters, `${source}` is name of the `DVI` file, `${page}` is page number of the converted image and `${output}` is name of the generated image.

You can compile your document using command

```
make4ht -c c.cfg test.tex
```

The build file is used automatically when it's named as the input TeX file with `.mk4` extension.

Last comment regarding math quality: it would best to use `mathml` format, because images have also other issues apart from resolution (accessibility, mismatch between font sizes, they don't align with baseline, and probably many more). The issue with `mathml` is a poor browser support, which is virtually non-existent apart from Firefox. Mathjax add good support for it to all browsers, but I fully understand that you don't like that. There is a possibility to use Mathjax at the compile time. This method replaces `mathml` with portable `HTML`, which can then be displayed without Javascript. See [Mathjax-node](https://github.com/mathjax/MathJax-node). Next version of Make4ht will provide option for this project.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I was not aware that `htlatex` had been replaced, but using `dvisvgm` this way solves the problem.

As far as dislike of MathJaX, for most documents it would be fine, but this one has too much going on (obviously the 2 1/2 was just an example xD) and it needs to display on old PC's fast. The MathJax compile time was way too long.

For accessibility...yeah SVG is a bummer, but could just put the MathML in between Aria code saying not to display, right?

Comment: @FredrickBrennan I meant using MathJax at compilation time, the resulting document looks like if MathJax was used, but it doesn't use any JavaScript at all.

Comment: Ah, OK, I understand. That would also work. Thanks again for the help. :)